# Get child nodes by searching for parent node using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

My XML structure is as under

```
<Employee>
    <categoryType>Name</categoryType>
    <groupNames>
        <name>ABC</name>
        <name>XYZ</name>
        <name>PQR</name>
    </groupNames>
</Employee>
```

I am trying to get hold of the child nodes by searching for parent node (categoryType = Name ).

Tried using all the following combinations , but none of them return the child nodes.

- `//*[contains(@categoryType,'Name')]/groupNames`
- `Employee/*(@categoryType,'Name')/groupNames`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching an **attribute** `categoryType` which doesn't exist. You have to match an **element**. Replace `@categoryType` for `categoryType` and you will have a different result.

This:

```
//*[contains(categoryType,'Name')]/groupNames
```

will get the categoryType node. And this:

```
//*[contains(categoryType,'Name')]/groupNames/name
```

will return a node-set with all three names.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.
However would like to understand the usage of these annotations, could you please direct me to any online documentation that might help